# Implement pessimistic locking

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sap-ase

I'm interested in how I can implement pessimistic locking, with very specific behavior.
(The reason I tagged the question with Sybase+Oracle+MSSQL, is because I'd be happy with a solution or "that's impossible!" for any one of them)

What I want is this:
1 - be able to lock a row (so that process can later do update, but no other process can lock the row)
2 - when another process tries to lock same row it should get notification that record is locked - I don't want this process to hang (I believe simple timeout can be used here)
3 - when another process tries to read record, it should be able to read it the way it is currently in database (but I don't want to use dirty reads).

The above 3 requirements are currently solved by application using shared memory - and performing record-locking outside database.  I'd like to move the locking into the database.

So far, I'm having conflicts between #1 and #3 - if I lock record by doing 'update ...' by updating a field to same value, than 'select' from another process hangs.

Edit:
I'm having some luck now with snapshot isolation level on MSSQL.  I can do both the locking, and reads without using dirty reads.

The reason I don't want to use dirty-reads, is that if a report is running, it might read multiple tables, and issue multiple queries.  Snapshot gives me a consistent snapshot of the datatabase.  With a dirty read, I'd have mismatching data - if there were any updates in the middle.

I think Oracle has snapshot as well, so now I'm most interested in Sybase.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you don't want to use dirty reads?  That's kind of the definition of what you're asking for in #3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle you can use select for update nowait to lock a record.

```
select * from tab where id=1234 for update nowait;
```

If another process  try to execute the same statment it gets an exception:

```
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified
```

until the first process(session) performs commit or rollback.

normally,  oracle don't permit dirty reads

Answer (score 0):

Your described conflict between #1 and #3 is a logical one: you can either let the database do dirty reads OR you block the reads. If you could read the locked row, it is a dirty read by definition. That has nothing to do with the specific database system you use!

So if you want it that way: Yes, what you want is impossible with all 3 systems because it hurts the definition of "dirty read".

Comment: There is no inherent conflict between #1 and #3.  That's what Oracle's multi-version read consistency does by default.  It disallows dirty reads, it prevents writers from blocking readers, and it prevents writers from blocking readers.  SQL Server's snapshot isolation level provides similar functionality.

Comment: @JustinCave yes there is a conflict: he want's to "be able to read it the way it is currently in database" in #3, but no dirty reads. But reading a locked element is a dirty read - granted: not by definition; but logically it doesn't make sense to implement a locking functionality which does not prevent anything. Am I right?

Comment: snapshot is I guess what I was looking for.  It locks out the writers, but not the readers. My statement that you quoted isn't great, but snapshot does allow me to read consistent data, even though it's not 'what is currently in database', it's consistent for some particular timeslice.